# How to save XML file from url using libcurl c++

Tags: c++, xml, libcurl

How can I save XML file from URL using libcurl c++ so I can load it with pugixml later on.
I've tried this and it's not working

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
...
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode result;
char *c_url = "http://some_url.xml";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "sth.xml";
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, c_url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
...
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_global_cleanup();
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: When you say "not working" is it "not working" in a specific way?

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well it doesn't even create a file.. am I missing something out?

Comment: Are you placing the file in a location where you are permitted to write?

Comment: I did `chmod u+w <filename>` but it's still not creating the file. It should create the file in my program's directory right?

Comment: You can always check... `if (!fp) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno)); }` after your `fopen` call.

Comment: ok so I've set permissions like this: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux) .. now it creates a file but it contains `<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="url_of_the_file_i_want_to_parse">here</a></body>`

Comment: @Rok you are encountering an HTTP redirect. Enable libcurl's `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

Comment: tried enabling this options but it now gives me empty file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested.. in the end, I end up using this code:

```
const char* f = "new_file.xml";
if (curl){
    const char* c_url = "some_url";

    FILE* ofile = fopen(f, "wb");
    if (!ofile) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno)); }

    if (ofile){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, c_url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ofile);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        fclose(ofile);
    }
}
pugi::xml_document doc;
doc.load_file(f);
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the bug by setting the `char*` to `const` as in:

```
char const* c_url = "http://some_url.xml";
```

Your code works fine for me.

However you don't always want to write the data you get receive disk. Sometimes you just want to keep it in memory to use it on the fly.

Here, I wrote a function to download the target of a URL into a `std::string` that you can do whatever you want with. I also made the code exception safe and generally safeer using a *smart pointer*.

```
// write the data into a `std::string` rather than to a file.
std::size_t write_data(void* buf, std::size_t size, std::size_t nmemb,
    void* userp)
{
    if(auto sp = static_cast<std::string*>(userp))
    {
        sp->append(static_cast<char*>(buf), size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    }

    return 0;
}

// To make the function thread safe you can use a smart pointer to
// hold your CURL session pointer.

// A deleter to use in the smart pointer for automatic cleanup
struct curl_dter{void operator()(CURL* curl) const
    { if(curl) curl_easy_cleanup(curl); }};

// A smart pointer to automatically clean up out CURL session
using curl_uptr = std::unique_ptr<CURL, curl_dter>;

// download the URL into a `std::string`.
std::string get_url(std::string const& url)
{
    std::string data;

    if(auto curl = curl_uptr(curl_easy_init()))
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl.get(), CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);

        CURLcode ec;
        if((ec = curl_easy_perform(curl.get())) != CURLE_OK)
            throw std::runtime_error(curl_easy_strerror(ec));

    }

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    auto xml = get_url("http://google.co.uk");

    std::cout << xml << '\n';

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

**Note:** I also added the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option in case the document has a *redirect* on it.